# StructureMap "WithCtorArg" "EqualTo" and nullable types

Tags: c#, structuremap, nullable

StructureMap doesn't like passing in Nullable types as constructor arguments. Is there a reason for this? Is there a way to get this to work?

```
[TestMethod]
public void Demo()
{
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.ForRequestedType<TestClass>()
                                    .TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<TestClass>()
                                    .WithCtorArg("param1").EqualTo((byte?)3));

//This fails, but works if it's non-nullable
    var result = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<TestClass>();
}

public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass(byte? param1)
    { }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying issue is that there's no difference, from the CLR's perspective, between a boxed (converted to `Object`) instance of a nullable type, and an (unboxed) instance of the equivalent non-nullable type.  Similarly, when you call GetType() on a nullable type like `int?`, the Type returned is indistinguishable from a regular `int`.   See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx more info about this.

This behavior is a recipe for disaster for code like StructureMap which interrogates types using GetType() on an Object-typed parameter. Since StructureMap doesn't know whether your `byte?` is actually nullable, when StructureMap code-gens the constructor call, it code-gens it as a regular `byte`, which bombs at runtime since StructureMap is passing the wrong type into the constructor call.

It'd be possible for StructureMap to work around this, but the changes would be non-trivial.  I tried a few tweaks to the StructureMap source code (e.g. changing from using Object and GetType() to instead using generic methods which accepted a generic parameter type, which could then be interrogated to see if it was a nullable type or not.  But there were more changes required (including, AFAIK, in the IL generation required to make the constructor call) and so I gave up.

You might want to bring this up with the Structure Map team itself who knows the code best.  The [StructureMap Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/structuremap-users?hl=en&pli=1) is a reasonable place to start.  Note that your question has been asked before (see end of [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/structuremap-users/browse_thread/thread/c3d83f27ee04d605/2fcaf37bd609d6ae?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=nullable#2fcaf37bd609d6ae)) so I'm not sure how responsive the Google Group is.

But, barring a fix in StructureMap itself, if I were you I'd consider wrapping your class in a simple wrapper which removes the need for a nullable parameter in the constructor.

Or if you're feeling brave, you can try to fix this by getting *very* familiar with the StructureMap source code. :-)

BTW, here's one example where the issue occurs in the StructureMap source:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the value of the constructor argument
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyValue"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T EqualTo(object propertyValue)
    {
        if(propertyValue.GetType().IsSimple())
            _instance.SetProperty(_propertyName, propertyValue.ToString());
        else
        {
            _instance.SetChild(_propertyName,new LiteralInstance(propertyValue));
        }
        return (T) _instance;
    }
```

By converting the propertyValue argument to an object, it's impossible for the method to know that it was a nullable type, since `byte?` and `byte` are indistinguishable once converted to Object.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code in the StructureMap source. Looks like it's not including nullable types.

```
protected internal bool IsSimple(Type type)
{
    return type.IsPrimitive || IsString(type) || IsEnum(type);
}
```

Comment: Turns out this code is not responsible, but I still don't know why this isn't supported.